# How Show data from for a miltiple list return by JSON funtion?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, linq

**My Models:**

---

**ClassAllocate:** Id, DepartmentId, CourseId, RoomId, DayId, StartTime, EndTime

**Course:** Id, CourseCode, CourseName, DepartmentId

**Room:** Id, RoomNumber

**Day:** Id, DayName

I am trying to search courses by department ID from "ClassAllocates" table in view page and trying to display only those courses schedule/allocation details.

I am using JSON to send lists from controller to view. I need to send multiple lists of list from a JsonResult function. I can send them ( I tried to send 2 lists), but, I can't display them. it is showing [object Object] or nothing or undefined in my attempts.

I am including my Controller funtion and Javascript in view:

**1st: Controller Function**

```
 public JsonResult GetCourseIdListByDepartmentId(int departmentId)
    {
        var x = db.ClassAllocates.DistinctBy(m => m.CourseId).Where(m => m.DepartmentId == departmentId).ToList();
        var r = db.ClassAllocates.DistinctBy(m => m.RoomId).Where(m => m.DepartmentId == departmentId).ToList();
        var all = new [] {x,r}.ToList();

        return Json(all, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**2nd: View Java Script**

```
<script>
$("#DepartmentId").change(function () {
    var dptId = $("#DepartmentId").val();
    //alert(dptId);
    $(".RowClass").empty();


    var json = {
        departmentId: dptId
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("GetCourseIdListByDepartmentId", "ClassAllocates")',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(json),
        success: function (data) {

            $.each(data, function (key, value) {

                $(".table2").append(
                        '<tr class="RowClass">' +
                        '<td>' + value.Couse + '</td>'

                        + '<tr>');
                });
        }
    });
});
```

This result in:
undefined

I need, CourseCode, CourseName and RoomNumber

Answer (score 0):

I got a way. As JSON returns List or list, then I need to write for loop twice after JSON success in View code or client side code.

```
$.each(data, function (key, value) {
                if (key==0) {
                    $.each(this, function (k, v) {
                        $(".table2").append(
                            '<tr class="RowClass">' +
                            '<td>' + v.Course.CourseCode + '</td>'

                            + '<tr>');
                    });
                }

                });
```

Now I am trying to pass and get more complex data.